# Problem with comparing negative numbers in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still new at VBA and I'm sure that this is a simple problem, but I'm comparing negative numbers who is lesser for example if I inputed textboxMIN to -7 and textboxMAX to -1 the result will be -1 will be less than -7. I don't know how to solve it because for me the condition is correct but the result isn't. Please take a look if there is a problem with my code

```
   '/************PROCESS***************/
    For t_int_iteratorI = 0 To txt_NumOperands.Value - 1
        MultiPage1.Pages.Add
        MultiPage1.Pages(t_int_iteratorI).Caption = "Variable" & t_int_iteratorI + 1

        Call sub_LabelPerPage
      Set p_var_SetTxtBox = frm_RangeForm.MultiPage1.Pages(t_int_iteratorI).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "MinBox")
        With p_var_SetTxtBox
            .Top = 50
            .Left = 100
        End With

     Set p_var_SetTxtBox = frm_RangeForm.MultiPage1.Pages(t_int_iteratorI).Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "MaxBox")
        With p_var_SetTxtBox
            .Top = 50
            .Left = 300
        End With
    Next t_int_iteratorI     

               p_var_MaxValue = frm_RangeForm.MultiPage1.Pages(t_int_iteratorI).maxbox.Value
               p_var_MinValue = frm_RangeForm.MultiPage1.Pages(t_int_iteratorI).MinBox.Value

                 If p_var_MinValue > p_var_MaxValue Then
                   MsgBox "MIN value should be lesser than MAX value."
                   Exit Sub
                 End If
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind that text boxes on a form contain string values that look like numbers, not actual numbers. You would want to do something like converting them to integers (into a new variable) using a `Int(x)` function or something along those lines before comparing them.

Comment: @braX Thank you! I did it, my variables was set to variant and i thought that it will be okay to set them to variant so that overflow will be avoided.

Comment: @VinIsLearning Variant is (almost) never a good solution. Only use it if there is no other option. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare all variables properly.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you for the information especially the Option Explicit and  I should be careful when using "Variant". Thank you